# mongodb find and update as once with function

Tags: mongodb

I ask myself if there is a way to use the aggregation framework or mapreduce of mongodb to perform data calculations and directly update a document field with the result. For example the document would look like this:

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    result: undefined
}
```

Now I would like to perform a process on each document of the collection and sum a + b of each document and finally store the result within the document like so:

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    result: 3
}
```

Maybe it works with mapreduce but I don't get it how it would work to update the document with mapreduce. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to the document itself in an update. You have to iterate/loop through the documents and read the required values and manipulate as per requirement and update each document using a function. See this answer for an example, or this one for server-side eval().

```
db.eval(function() { 
        db.collection.find({"add criteria if required"}).forEach(function(document) {
            document.result = document.a + document.b;
            db.collection.save(document);
        });
    });
```

[More details](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/server-side-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [mongo bulk update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) instead of map-reduce as below :

```
var bulk = db.collectionName.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var counter = 0;
db.collectionName.find().forEach(function(data) {
    var updoc = {
      "$set": {}
    };
    var myKey = "result";
    updoc["$set"][myKey] = data.a + data.b
      // queue the update
    bulk.find({
      "_id": data._id
    }).update(updoc);
    counter++;
    // Drain and re-initialize every 1000 update statements
    if(counter % 1000 == 0) {
      bulk.execute();
      bulk = db.collectionName.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
  })
  // Add the rest in the queue
if(counter % 1000 != 0) bulk.execute();
```